# div boxes under each other responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css

im trying to build a Website wich is based on bootstrap. i build a grid sistem with two `col` in each `row`  they have the class `"col-md-8"` and `"col-md-4"`. what i whant is that if someone is viewing the Website on a tablet for example that the two `col` should be under each other .

the `col-md-8` has a Image inside and if i make the browser Window smaller to see how it would look like on tablets the text is getting from the height longer and the pic smaller. so they are still next to each other but i would like to have them under each other.

**Example Code**

```
<div class="item"> <!--Slide Block 2 -->
    <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <img class="featurette-image img-responsive" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="T & M Limousinen Exklusive Transferfahrten" img src="img/placeholder_2.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3 class="featurette-heading">Exklusiv und komfortabel <span class="text-muted"> bis zum Ziel</span></h3>
            <p class="lead">
                Ob regional oder bundesweit, T&M ist für Ihre Transferfahrten der richtige Partner. Exklusivität, Komfort und Diskretion stehen an oberster Stelle.

                Unsere Gäste werden direkt nach Verlassen des Flugzeuges, vom Hotel oder bei ihren Geschäftsterminen abgeholt. Wir bieten unseren Gästen somit höchste Flexibilität und den größtmöglichen Komfort für Geschäftsreisen oder Privatbesuche.
            </p>
            <p class="lead">
                Nutzen Sie die Möglichkeit, komfortabel, sicher und entspannt zu Ihren Terminen zu gelangen.

                Wir fahren Sie innerhalb der Hansestadt Hamburg oder bundesweit stets pünktlich zu Ihren Zielen. In unseren Limousinen werden Transfers zu Geschäftsterminen, Messen, Hotels, Flughafen zum exklusiven Erlebnis.

                Gerne unterbreiten wir Ihnen Ihr persönliches Angebot.
            </p>
            <p class="lead">
                Anfragen richten Sie bitte per Mail an <a href="mailto:info@limousinenservice.de">info@limousinenservice.de</a> oder per Telefon an 040/500182-0.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a link where I uploaded the preview [link](http://limo.awesom-media.de)

Comment: But in your preview, you are not using col-md-8...I am not finding this line in rendered HTML <div class="col-md-8">!

Comment: sorry, my bad. i updated , now it is

Comment: im using it. its the section under Leistung. the red Image where is inside written 1140*600 - that is the col-md-8  . try it with strg+r to refresh the site

Comment: try to add clearfix class in div's. Might be it solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `col-sm-` It is basically for Small devices Tablets with the width of 768px and higher

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12"></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"></div>
```

Comment: I made mistake. Please remove the . before col-sm-6 and try again. I just updated the code.

Comment: i tryed it without it. still not working . [IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/2mqqq7d.jpg[/IMG] thats how it Looks like when i make my browser Windows smaller. but what i would like to have is like this [IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/2v31v6t.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: on my i phone is it working the way it is. but on other devices not. on Fullscreen is it working too. but on tablets it Looks like that . text to Long and img to small and next to each other

Comment: which version of bootstrap you are working, is it 3.0 ? I just update with new class. It must work.

Comment: the new on . i downloadet few hours ago

Comment: If you want full row for each div in tablet then you may use col-sm-12

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6"></div>
```

Comment: no, dosnt work.

the reason why this is so important is because of the layout. here is a preview of the layout and u see that left is an Image right the text and it just dont look good if one of them is taller. the must have the same height . so thats why  i would like to have them on tablets under each other . or is there a nother way to get this layout on tablets ? [IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/55hvmp.jpg[/IMG]